# Cygwin/Git/Gitosis unable to push new repository

Tags: git, cygwin, gitosis

I've recently set up cygwin, git, and gitosis on my Windows Server 2003 box and am having troubles.  I've followed just about every tutorial I can find to the letter, and have confirmed that my git account's authorized_keys table is getting updated when I push the gitosis-admin repository.  I seem to be stuck, however, when it comes to creating a new repository.

I've seen many tutorials that recommend the following code (obviously the repo name changes), tried in both git bash and windows command line:

```
mkdir free_monkey
cd free_monkey
git init
touch README
git add .
git commit -m "Added blank readme"
git remote add origin git@my_server:free_monkey.git
git push origin master
```

When I execute the last line (no matter exactly what I send), it says "The remote end hung up unexpectedly":
$ git push -v origin master:refs/heads/master
Pushing to git@my_server:free_monkey.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

My gitosis.conf file looks like the following:

```
[gitosis]
loglevel = DEBUG

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin free_monkey.git free_monkey
members = git@my_server @all
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any information you need to help me debug this.  Thank you!

One other thing that concerns me:

```
$ ssh git@my_server git 
DEBUG:gitosis.serve.main:Got command 'git' 
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Unknown command denied
```

Is that maybe the problem? If so, how do I fix that?

Comment: Add that as an edit to your post to preserve formatting.

Comment: Thanks Blaenk, I added it to my question.  First time asking a question on StacckOverflow; didn't know I could edit my question.

Comment: The "command denied" part is, indeed, your clue -- the git on the remote server isn't working properly. Unfortunately I have zero experience with setting up git on Windows, but I would suggest at a minimum checking that you can run git there successfully outside of gitosis -- try a 'git init' command somewhere, for example. Check that git is in the gitosis user's path, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, it seems that the "Unknown command denied" error was a red herring.  Gitosis only allows for the commands that actually get sent across during a git push/pull process for security reasons, so "git" was not a known command.

I continued receiving the same error, but stumbled-upon a reference to the authorized_keys file in another forum - **having duplicate keys ruins the authorized_keys file completely**.  Sure enough, that was my problem.  Hope this helps someone out there.

To really diagnose this, follow these steps:

1. cat your authorized_keys files for the user you're using to access your git repositories (mine was git@my_server, so I looked in /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys).  Make sure you have each public key only once.
2. I ran into a second problem, which was that I was trying to use multiple ppk's with TortoiseGit and Pageant.  **Pageant seems to ignore TortoiseGit's request to change keys**; right click on Pageant in your taskbar (the computer wearing a hat) and View Keys, then remove all keys that don't match the public key you want to use (could be all of them).

I now have gitosis running on my server available over SSH, accessible via TortoiseGit.

Comment: I've since switched away from using Gitosis to a custom-made solution that uses different usernames and effectively creates a git-hub like situation.  I'm interested in sharing the code, but wrote it in C# (I have a good portion in Python, but am simply not very experienced in the language) and would like to get it in a reusable state for others.  If anyone's interested, I'll post it up on github to share.

Answer (score 0):

You probably made a typo on the first time or something. Try removing the origin and re-adding it:

```
git rm origin
git remote add origin git@my_server:free_monkey.git
```

Then try pushing again. It's worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I've been trying that.  I'm still getting "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"... I've also tried different users before the @, and they aren't working either.  Thanks for the quick suggestion.